# Radio button value regardless of selected input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<input type="radio" name="pay" id="payid" value="banktransfer"> Bank Transfer <br/>
<input type="radio" name="pay" id="payid" value="paypal"> PayPal <br/> <br/>
```

I try:

```
var sample = $('#payid').val()
alert(sample);
```

Why I have still `banktransfer`? (regardless of the selected input)?

Answer (score 2):

The id must be unique. Radios need the same name for their on-off functionality to work, but each must have a unique id. You could, for instance, have "payid1" and "payid2"

Comment: This isn't the only problem, and will not actually get the desired result

Answer (score 2):

The ID attribute must be unique across the page. In your case jQuery is just picking the first element with that ID and returning that value. This code will get you the selected value.

```
jQuery("input[name=pay]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var sample = $("[name=pay]:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which one of the radio buttons you want, you can get the correct one (the checked one) by using the `:checked` selector. You also need to use the `name` attribute selector, because `id` needs to be unique and JQuery will only ever return the first match.

This should work for you:

```
var sample = $('[name="pay"]:checked').val();
alert(sample);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMEej/)